# VBA - Formulário que alimenta uma planilha com valores

Tags: vba

Caros, sou novo em VBA e para meu projeto estou tentando fazer um userform que alimente uma planilha de acordo com as informações que o usuário inputar. Estou tendo um erro que não entendo como resolver..

O erro mostra ser na linha: Lin = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

Segue o script:

```
Private Sub Enter_Click()
Dim iLin As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ADAE")

lin = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

If Trim(Me.title) = "" Then
MsgBox "Informe o Título da Planilha"
Me.title.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If Not (IsNumeric(Me.nidaula)) Then
MsgBox "Digite um número válido"
Me.nidaula.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If Not (Me.TM) And Not (Me.TC) Then
        MsgBox "Selecione o tipo de tarefa"
        Exit Sub
        End If

If Not (IsNumeric(Me.group)) Then
MsgBox "Digite um número válido"
Me.nidaula.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

ws.Cells(lin, 1).Value = Me.title.Value
ws.Cells(lin, 2).Value = Me.nidaula.Value
 If (Me.TM) Then
        ws.Cells(lin, 3) = "2"
    Else
        ws.Cells(lin, 3) = "3"
    End If
ws.Cells(l, 4).Value = Me.group.Value
ws.Columns("A:D").AutoFit

Me.title.Value = ""
Me.nidaula.Value = ""
Me.TM.Value = False
Me.TC.Value = False
Me.group.Value = ""
Me.title.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Para dar maior legibilidade, poderia utilizar [esta ferramenta](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) de *indentation* para o VBA? E poderia fornecer informações de como os dados estão na Planilha ADAE e colunax A e B, em que o erro ocorre? Pode ser imagem ou preferencialmente [uma tabela](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) para reproduzir o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você possui um **typo error (erro de digitação)** na linha: `lin = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row`

**O correto seria:** `lin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`

Ou seja, utilizar `.End(xlUp)` com **L** e não `.End(x1Up)` com **1**

> Um modo de evitar typo errors é a utilização do `Option Explicit`

Em que um código de exemplo pode ser visto a seguir:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Exemplo_Option_Explicit()
    Dim lin As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")

    lin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'Correto
    lin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row 'Errado
End Sub
```

A parte do código que possui erro de digitação ou não foi declarada será destacada.

[image: Erro destacado]

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não enxerguei isso de maneira alguma! Valeu pela dica do option explicit, vai me ajudar bastante!